# Is the simulator a good judge for iOS compatability?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

This is a more general question. If I am developing an iOS app (or game) and it works fine on the devices I have (ex. iPod 3g, iPhone 4, and iPad 1 + 2), and it works fine on the simulator for devices I don't have (iPhone 3g, iPhone 5, iPad 3), can I trust that everything will work on the real devices exactly the same as the simulators? I've read all around and have experienced differences between the simulators and real devices. But since I get what I expect from the devices I do have and from the simulators that I don't, would it be reasonable to assume that my application would behave properly, if I am absolutely unable to get my hands on the real devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many things, you are probably safe since you have tested on real devices. The iPhone 5 has the bigger screen but the iPhone 5 simulator should be good enough to test that your app works on the bigger display. The real iPhone 5 uses armv7s, not armv7. So it's possible some highly optimized code or timing code could be different. The iPad 3 has the retina screen but this can be tested in the retina iPad simulator. Very few devs have every device with every version of iOS they support. You've done a good job with what you have. I'd be comfortable with what you've done but it really depends on what your app does and how it pushes the OS and the device.

I'd be more concerned with testing your app across all versions of iOS that your app supports. iOS bugs get fixed, there are differences in behaviors from 4.3 to 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I will second that. We run a lot of apps on different devices, but for example, we don't test on the 4S, but we would test on iOS 4.3, 5.0, 5.0.1, 5.1, and 6.0, as some code is OS dependent. For devices, iPhone 3GS, 4, 5, iPad 1, 3. We leave out iPad 2, and the iPhone 4S. We don't test any iPod Touch at all.

As for your question, it all depends on what your app does, and whether there are any OS specific functions, or device specific features. If not, then you should be fine to rely on the simulator for those you don't have.